# Is partial_sort_copy the fastest C++ partial sort?

Tags: c++, sorting

Consider the following function, `median`:

```
  real_t median(const std::initializer_list<real_t> vars) {
    real_t tmp[15];
    const unsigned x = vars.size() / 2;
    if (x & 1) {
      std::partial_sort_copy(vars.begin(), vars.end(), &tmp[0], &tmp[x]);
      return tmp[x];
    }
    const unsigned y = x + 1;
    std::partial_sort_copy(vars.begin(), vars.end(), &tmp[0], &tmp[y]);
    return (tmp[x] + tmp[y]) / 2;
  }
```

I am using a partial sort to decrease complexity, as I only need to sort half of the list.

Further, I have assumed that `std::partial_sort_copy` is faster than `std::partial_sort` or `std::nth_element` because there is no shuffling required in the sort algorithm (It1 != It2). Is my assumption correct?

---

NB: Assume `real_t` could be a `double`, so please don't criticise the use of division.

NBB: I'm using `-pedantic` and `vars` is known to not be longer than 15 elements.

Comment: you could try the other ones and see

Comment: This Q+A should still exist on the internet somewhere for someone else to find. Whether I end up having to actually benchmark them myself and find out, we'll see.

Comment: Surely you realize that for just 15 elements even Bubble-sorting the whole list would be adequate...

Comment: First of all, you can just test it. Different implementations have different speed. Second, the asymptotic complexity of `nth_element` is linear while the other two is linearithmic. Third, `partial_sort_copy` need allocate memory and copy elements, so it is likely slower.

Comment: `partial_sort_copy` throws more memory at the problem, but it's a double-edged sword. If you overflow the CPU cache, a larger working set reduces performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I could choose, I would go for a Partial Quicksort.

[Info on Partial Quicksort](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~conrado/research/talks/sem-carleton04.pdf)

But if you have to compare these two only... then Partial sort is better vs partial sort copy. Here you have more info about these two methods:

[Info on Partial Sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort)

[Info on Partial Sort Copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort_copy)

Here you also find an algorithm code example for Partial Quicksort - it was implemented in C and matlab:

[Example - Partial Quicksort](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23576-minmax-selection)

Comment: Those slides are a little complex for easy consumption. Does it have a standard library implementation?

Comment: w.r.t your edit, I get the impression then that std::nth_element is actually faster than both for larger sets because it boasts `O(n)` complexity rather than `Onlog(m)`.

Comment: just added a link with example of implementation for Partial Quicksort - have a look.

Comment: keep in mind that std::nth_element will be O(N * N) and not O(n) complexity in the worst case http://www-home.fh-konstanz.de/~bittel/prog2/Praktikum/musser97introspective.pdf .

Comment: What leads you to believe this one quicksort is faster than any `std::partial_sort` implementation? `partial_sort` is allowed to use quicksort, but usually doesn't because other algorithms are generally agreed to be faster on average.

Comment: `partial_sort` and `nth_element` won't work on an `initialization_list` since the init list can't be modified.  You'd need to make a copy into another container first, use `partial_sort_copy`, or pass in some other type of parameter (a different container type or a begin/end set of non-const random access iterators).

Answer (score 9):

Using the following code

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

volatile int answer;

const int size = 15;

std::array<std::array<int, size>, 0x100> fresh_data;
std::array<std::array<int, size>, 0x100> data;

void naive(int n) {
    auto & a = data[n];
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    answer = a[size / 2];
}

void fancy(int n) {
    auto & a = data[n];
    std::partial_sort(a.begin(), a.begin() + (size / 2 + 1), a.end());
    answer = a[size / 2 ];
}

void ghoul(int n) {
    auto & a = data[n];
    std::array<int, size / 2 + 1> temp;
    std::partial_sort_copy(a.begin(), a.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
    answer = temp[size / 2];

}

void nthel(int n) {
    auto & a = data[n];
    std::nth_element(a.begin(), a.begin() + size / 2, a.end());
    answer = a[size / 2];
}

void gen_data() {
    for (auto & a : fresh_data)
    for (auto & b : a)
        b = rand();
}

void regen_data() {
    data = fresh_data;
}


template <typename T>
void test(T f, std::string n) {
    regen_data();
    auto a = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (auto i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    for (auto i = 0; i < 0x100; ++i)
        f(i);
    auto b = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << n << ": " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(b - a).count() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    gen_data();
    test(naive, "             std::sort");
    test(fancy, "     std::partial_sort");
    test(ghoul, "std::partial_sort_copy");
    test(nthel, "      std::nth_element");
}
```

I get the following results:

```
             std::sort: 141
     std::partial_sort: 359
std::partial_sort_copy: 831
      std::nth_element: 149
```

Tested using Visual Studio 2013 in 64bit release mode on an AMD Phenom II x4 2.5GHz.

Comment: In terms of the standard library this is actually the benchmark that people might be looking for to test on a data set of required size.

Comment: Numbers for gcc/clang xcode5 on Mavericks:
             `std::sort`: 126
     `std::partial_sort`: 1278
`std::partial_sort_copy`: 2486
      `std::nth_element`: 260

Comment: Isn't this benchmark a bit unfair in that 3 of the 4 methods tested modify their inputs (to be sorted), which they benefit from in the subsequent iterations?

Comment: I just tested two variants - one using 1 iteration over 1000000 random arrays instead of 10000 iterations over the same 256 arrays; and another where the 3 in question copied the input array rather than taking a reference. In both cases the performance gaps are much narrower than the original benchmark, but in fact the relative rankings are pretty similar.

Comment: Also FWIW, at moderate array sizes (eg 1000), `nth_element` is substantially faster both when allowing input mutation and not.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested your code?

`std::partial_sort_copy(vars.begin(), vars.end(), &tmp[0], &tmp[x]);` will not copy anything to `tmp[x]` since `&tmp[x]` is considered the end of the half-open range (ie., it's just past the last valid element).  So your `return` statements access indeterminate or default constructed array elements.

Try the following:

```
real_t median(const std::initializer_list<real_t> vars) 
{
    real_t tmp[15];

    size_t siz = vars.size();
    if ((siz == 0) || (15 < siz)) return 0;     // or throw some sort of exception or ???

    const unsigned x = vars.size() / 2;
    std::partial_sort_copy(vars.begin(), vars.end(), &tmp[0], &tmp[x+1]);

    if (siz % 2 == 0) {
        return (tmp[x-1] + tmp[x]) / 2;
    }

    return tmp[x];
}
```

Note that if given an `initializer_list` as the source of data, a modify-in-place algorithm such as `nth_element` or `partial_sort` won't work since initializer lists can't be modified (whether the parameter is marked `const` or not - the iterators into the `initializer_list` are `const` qualified). So a copy must be done to find the median using the standard algorithm functions, either by copying the list before calling the algorithm, or by using an algorithm variant that performs the copy as part of its work, such as `partial_sort_copy()`.

Comment: No, I haven't tested it. It's pre-birth optimisation ;) Thanks for the answer, it's very helpful.